# How do I prevent Electron from swallowing keys (especially shortcuts that control the screen reader/accessibility tools)?

Tags: linux, electron

Users of our Electron app on Linux are unable to use some global shortcuts for other applications.

Specifically, in normal use `Insert+Space` should bring up [Orca](https://help.gnome.org/users/orca/stable/introduction.html.en) configuration options. However, when the Electron app has focus, the shortcut doesn't work -- I'm assuming because the keyboard event is swallowed by Electron.

What can I do within Electron to pass the keyboard event up and prevent swallowing it?

Also, to make it more complicated, the specific keyboard shortcut can be configured so a solution shouldn't rely on a hard-coded list of allowable key events.